# Cannot configure manual shortcuts in TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio, shortcut

I'm trying to change some of the default shortcuts in TeXstudio's Preferences panel, but when I try to enter a custom key combination for a shortcut the command(cmd), option, control(ctrl), and shift key are not recognised (i.e. nothing happens when I press the key). I can select various combinations involving those keys from the preconfigured dropdown menu, but even then the shortcuts don't work. I suspect that the underlying problem is the same, namely that somehow TeXstudio doesn't recognise the keys correctly for some reason.

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Comment: So let asuume that you want to change the sehortcut for italics from Ctrl+I to Ctrl+Shift+I and you are in Options->Configure TeXstudio->Shortcuts->Menus->LaTeX->Font Styles->Italics and then you press with your mouse under the third column of this page namely "Additional Shortcut" which turns blue and you enter the combination Ctrl+Shift+I and nothing happens?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Isolated numbers and letters like "1" or "a" will show up when I type in the field, but as soon as I try to enter a combination involving command, control, option, or shift, nothing shows up.

Comment: In an odd turn of events, I can now enter combinations that involve one out of shift, command, option, control, but no combinations like shift+cmd+1 or option+cmd+1. In any case, the bigger problem is that even when I manage to enter a shortcut, it does not work. For example, I tried to set a shortcut for "Build & View". Weirdly, in the preferences this seems to be called "Presentation" located under "Menus PDF-Viewer/View/Presentation", which is set to F5 by default. When I use F5 the shortcut works, i.e. it does execute Build & View, but when I add a custom shortcut it does not work.

Comment: I've also tried my custom shortcut in "Menus-PDF Viewer/Edit/Quick Build", since this name would make more sense to me for the Build & View command, but it doesn't do anything either.

Comment: The default shortcuts work? This problem started from the first time you installed TeXstudio or after a time of normal shortcut operation?

Comment: Yes, the default shortcuts work. I've just switched to TeXstudio from TeXmaker, and the problem existed ever since I installed TeXstudio.

Comment: Are you working under windows?

Comment: No, I'm on macOS Ventura.

Comment: I am not familiar with macOS. I suggest that you unistall the Texstudio. Then find any "hidden" folders of Texstudio or Texmaker remain after the unistall and delete them. You have to do a research (google) to find their location(s). Restart your computer and do a fresh clean istallation of the latest TexStudio. I suspect that the problem occures due to old settings of Texmaker that remains in your system after the unistall of Texmaker.

Comment: I don't see how this would work since Texmaker and Texstudio are separate applications. I even know people that use both simultaneously. I followed your advice anyway and reinstalled Texstudio from scratch, but unfortunately it didn't solve my issue.

Comment: Don't forget that TexStudio born from Texmaker. Have you taken care to delete any remaining folders after the unistall?

Comment: Sure, but they're still separate applications. I don't see how settings in one would affect the other. They're in separate folders and don't share any files, e.g. .plist files where preferences are stored. As I mentioned, there are no issues running both applications in parallel with different settings. And yes, I've uninstalled everything.